# Google Closure : How to render 2 components

Tags: user-interface, components, google-closure

I have 2 goog.ui.component say component1 and component2 i have to render both.

```
var bottom_content = goog.dom.getElement('diag_details');
component1.render(bottom_content);
component2.render(bottom_content);
```

above code give error "Component already rendered".

Is there any way render multiple goog.ui.component.

Comment: you will have to create two instances. 1 component can only exist once in a display tree

Comment: Can you provide the code where you initialize component1 and component2?

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that the component was already rendered, either directly or indirectly (it was a child of another element which was rendered).